# Getting old node field value in update hook

Tags: nodes

Hi I'm using the node update hook in my custom .module file in my Drupal 9 site. I have a field called `field_amount`. And I was wondering if I can access the old value of that field within my update hook and the new value too?

```php
function custom_module_node_update(\Drupal\node\NodeInterface $node) {
  //access the old value of field_amount and the new value
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [the docs](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_update/10) say:

```
Get the original entity object from $entity->original.
```

In your case that would be, for example:

```
function custom_module_node_update(\Drupal\node\NodeInterface $node) {
  $old_field_value = $node->original->field_foo->value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works!